# jquery mobile ui-grid with ui-blocks of equal height

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to use the built-in ui-grid in jquery mobile for a 3 column layout.

The problem are the ui-bars inside the ui-blocks when they have a different height. I'd like to have all 3 columns to have the same height as the highest column.

Does anyone know a simple solution to this problem? I'd like to solve it with just CSS but I didn't manage it. Is JS really the only solution to this problem?

JsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/zHbuC/466/

Code:

```
<div data-role="page" id="station" class="type-home">
    <div data-role="header"><h1>Header Page 1</h1></div>

    <div data-role="content" data-theme="b">
        <div class="ui-grid-b" style="text-align:center">
            <div class="ui-block-a">
                <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-c">A</div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b">
                <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-c">B</div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-c">
                <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-c">
                    <p>B with alot of text</p>
                    <p>with lots of lines</p>
                    <p>another line</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer"><h4>Footer</h4></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my experience the only "reliable" soloution is using a simple jquery height comparison. It only takes a couple of lines.

```
var tallest = 0;
$('.ui-grid-b > div').each(function() {
    var thisHeight = $(this).height();
    if(thisHeight > tallest) {
        tallest = thisHeight;
    }
});
$('.ui-grid-b .ui-bar').height(tallest);
```

Or do it as a function, see http://www.cssnewbie.com/equal-height-columns-with-jquery/

If you wan't CSS on the other hand, there is a buggy/unrelaible method using the box-model.
See: http://www.css3.info/introducing-the-flexible-box-layout-module/

Else there are some HTML/CSS hacks, which work, but produce "ugly" code.
See: http://buildinternet.com/2009/07/four-methods-to-create-equal-height-columns/

---

jQuery example:
http://jsfiddle.net/zHbuC/468/

And a minified example (only works if content is always in the `.ui-bar`)

```
var tallest = 0;
$('.ui-grid-b .ui-bar').each(function() {
    if($(this).height() > tallest) {tallest = $(this).height();}
}).height(tallest);
```

Comment: Thank you so far! I see, a javscript solution seems to be really the best solution. But unfortunately I'm loading the page with ajax. I have registered the "pageinit" event for my page but the height of every ui-bar is always returned as 0. I'm looking into it now and then I'll report back

Comment: Yea, it becomes alittle bit more tricky like that. I guess i would make it a function, and on load succes, run the function if the content contains `.equal-height" or something like that. Becomes a lot tricker if the same function must load different pages :)

Comment: Almost there! Binding to the "pageshow" event gives me the correct height of every ui-bar. But this has the ugly side effect that the new height gets applied after 1-2 seconds, so I see the original height before the "tallest height" gets applied. Also this only works when navigating through ajax. After a full page reload it doesn't work again. It feels so weird to work with jquery mobile at first. Not sure yet if I like it or not. Marked your answer as answered nonetheless since this resolved my initial issue, thanks alot!

Comment: Hmm shouldn't take that long.. Might be an idea to give it an relative high css ´min-height´ to give it a more normal look, which the jquery then will override with the right value.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue-- my solution might be a bit more generic than the one above-- should work with any of the grids.

http://jsfiddle.net/zHbuC/816/

I had an issue with grids within grids-- here is my jsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/48uce/

you can change the content in the grids and the heights will resize.

Here is my utility class which accomplishes this-- it might be a bit of overkill:

```
var ekJqm = {};

ekJqm.utilities = {
    fixGrids: function (container) {
        $("[class^=ui-block-]").each(function () {
            $(this).removeAttr("style");
            $(">div", this).removeAttr("style");
        });
        var fixBlocks = function (blocks) {
            blocks = $(blocks);
            var heights = [];
            blocks.each(function () {
                if ($.inArray($(this).height(), heights) == -1)
                    heights.push($(this).height());
            });
            if (heights.length == 1)
                return;
            var maxHeight = 0;
            blocks.each(function () {
                if ($(this).height() > maxHeight)
                    maxHeight = $(this).height();
            });
            blocks.each(function () {
                $(this).height(maxHeight);
                var adjust = $(">div", this).outerHeight() - $(">div", this).height();
                $(">div", this).height(maxHeight - adjust);
            });
        };

        $("[class^=ui-grid-]", container).each(function () {
            var maxHeight = 0;
            var blocks = $(">[class^=ui-block-]", this);
            var set = [];
            var tempSet = [];
            blocks.each(function (index) {
                var _class = $(this).attr("class");
                if ($.inArray(_class, tempSet) >= 0) {
                    fixBlocks(set);
                    tempSet = [];
                    set = [];
                }
                set.push(this);
                tempSet.push(_class);
                if (index == blocks.length - 1)
                    fixBlocks(set);
            });
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Hi ek_ny, thanks for your answer. I haven't tried your solution since I solved it with the previous solution by Marco Johannessen but I'm sure it will be helpful for others.
Cheers Simon

Comment: @Simon - my pleasure-- would be nice if it were built into jquery mobile.. ;)

Comment: @ek_ny - Is not JQM open source? become a contributer and add your code into the next release!